# Change of parameters on ouput graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, output

I have generated the graph, but i lost the settings, i would like to make the Plotmarkers slightly bigger. Is there anything to do this without redoing the computation?[image]

Like Show[%1,PlotMarker->{dot,10}]
Slightly making the question more general and useful for other users! If i want to change other parameters... is there a general recipe / command somewhere we can find to make changes?

Comment: `% /. Point[a__] :> {PointSize[0.2], Point[a]}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possibility. Copy the graphic into a new cell, type `p1 =` in front of the plot and evaluate the cell. Then, do

```
p1 /. Point[a__] :> {PointSize[0.2], Point[a]}
```

Here's a gif showing the procedure:

[image]

Comment: Very good! method ... Just wondering if if this method is true in general? If i want to change to plot marker symbol? or let's say now i regret my choice of axis from 0 to 0.5.. i want to plot from 0 to 6.

Comment: @elpsyCongroo. Some of these things you can do with `Show`; e.g. changing the plot range is as simple as `Show[p1, PlotRange -> {0, 6}]`. Changing the `PlotMarkers` on the fly is a lot more difficult. In that case, it might be better to just extract the points from the plot directly and make a new figure. There are many questions on this site about extracting the points in a plot.